# Linearity of the Wavelet Transform

Tags: linear-transformations

The wavelet transform $W[s(t)]$ of a signal $s(t)$ is linear for real or complex $a$ and $b$.

$$W[a s_1(t)+ b s_2(t)] = a W[s_1(t)]+ b W[s_2(t)]$$

How can I show the above and for the specific Daubechies Wavelets (D2 to D20) ?

Have seen the definition of the Wavelet Function

$$ X(a,b) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\overline{\Psi\left(\frac{t - b}{a}\right)} x(t)\, dt $$

But this is not helping me much, as it is very generic.

Comment: Write down the definition of the wavelet transform and verify the claim.

Comment: That's what I am asking.

Comment: Can you show me how to verify it for `D4` with hints of how to verify for the rest of them?